# Enumerating serial port list in menu tab - python

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

How can i get the serial port list in the sub menu from the qt `menuBar()`

```
Select Port| debug | help
  |           
list comports -com1
               com2
               com3
```

some part of my code

```
def Menu(self, event):  
    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Select Port')
    fileMenu.addAction(self.conn2)

def createActions(self):
    self.conn2 = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('./some_image.png'),"&Connect", self,
                                  statusTip="Sellect ur com port", triggered=self.connect)
```

i need to get the list of available com ports in the sub menu of the Select Port tab or open a new dialog box with serial Ports listed

Answer (score 0):

Basically iterate through a list of available ports and add them as a kind of radio button checkable actions or as a `QComboBox`.  Then when one gets selected, change your `self.portName` to reflect the new one.

The example in pure Qt for doing this is under the Terminal Qt Serial Port example, under the `SettingsDialog`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-settingsdialog-cpp.html

```
void SettingsDialog::fillPortsInfo()
{
    ui->serialPortInfoListBox->clear();
    static const QString blankString = QObject::tr("N/A");
    QString description;
    QString manufacturer;
    QString serialNumber;
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        QStringList list;
        description = info.description();
        manufacturer = info.manufacturer();
        serialNumber = info.serialNumber();
        list << info.portName()
             << (!description.isEmpty() ? description : blankString)
             << (!manufacturer.isEmpty() ? manufacturer : blankString)
             << (!serialNumber.isEmpty() ? serialNumber : blankString)
             << info.systemLocation()
             << (info.vendorIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.vendorIdentifier(), 16) : blankString)
             << (info.productIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.productIdentifier(), 16) : blankString);

        ui->serialPortInfoListBox->addItem(list.first(), list);
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like `PyQt` has the `QtSerialPort` library (probably because `pySerial` and similar libraries are already available).

Hope that helps.

Comment: PyQt5 has QtSerialPort (since version 5.1).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for keeping me honest.